# Реализация интерфейса Account Service

Tags: java

Всем привет. Программа не проходит проверку в редакторе кода. Пишет "Failed. Wrong answer". В IDEA ошибок нет.

```
interface AccountService {
    /**
     * It finds an account by owner id
     *
     * @param id owner unique identifier
     * @return account or null
     */
    Account findAccountByOwnerId(long id);

    /**
     * It count the number of account with balance > the given value
     *
     * @param value
     * @return the number of accounts
     */
    long countAccountsWithBalanceGreaterThan(long value);
}

// Declare and implement your AccountServiceImpl here
class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    Account[] accounts;

    public AccountServiceImpl(Account[] accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts.clone();
    }

    public Account findAccountByOwnerId(long id) {
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.getId() == id) {
                return account;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long countAccountsWithBalanceGreaterThan(long value) {
        long counter = 0;
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.getBalance() > value) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}

class Account {

    private long id;
    private long balance;
    private User owner;

    public Account(long id, long balance, User owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}

class User {

    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Вам дан интерфейс с именем AccountService. Интерфейс имеет два абстрактных метода:

findAccountByOwnerId(long id)возвращает Accountнайденный по идентификатору владельца или null.
countAccountsWithBalanceGreaterThan(long balance) это возвращает количество счетов с балансом больше, чем переданное значение.
Есть также два других класса: Account(id, balance, owner) и User(id, firstName, lastName). Смотрите их реализации в предоставленном шаблоне кода.

Вам необходимо реализовать AccountServiceинтерфейс и два его метода.

- Ваша реализация должна быть названа AccountServiceImpl. Он должен иметь конструктор с одним аргументом - массив учетных записей.
- Реализация должна держать массив внутри.
- Первый метод должен искать учетную запись по идентификатору владельца в массиве, второй - подсчитывать количество учетных записей, которые удовлетворяют заданному условию в массиве.

Вот пример экземпляра:

Account[] accounts = ...
AccountService service = new AccountServiceImpl(accounts);
Примечание: не делайте классы и интерфейсы public.

Comment: все потому, что вы не выполнили задание в соответствии с описанием, тот факт, что код компилируется, еще ничего не значит. ваш метод findAccountByOwnerId должен по заданию осуществлять поиск по идентификатору владельца, а не идентификатору аккаунта, а вы ищите по идентификатору аккаунта. отсюда и ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже подметили в комментарии, ошибка в методе findAccountByOwnerId(). В самом имени метода кроется ответ на Ваш вопрос.
Еще почему-то я не увидел @Override над методами.
И также в методе countAccountsWithBalanceGreaterThan() может ругаться компилятор: если long counter = 0, а не 0L